# Embed WAVE-files in iPhones' Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, html, safari, quicktime, mobile-safari

I host a WAVE-file, which plays fine, it's URL is entered in Mobile Safari directly.
Trying to embed it in a simple HTML page shows me a "can't play" icon:

[image]

What's wrong with my embed code?

```
<embed href="http://localhost/test.wav" type="audio/wav"/>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your embed code is ... you didn't post it here.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you. The code was actually included in the post. But somehow stackoverflow's rich text editor made it disappear. Sorry, I haven't seen that. Now it's corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a server problem. Apache has a special mode for downloading the file. You need it for embedding the audio, as I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

MobileSafari does not support the embed tag. You can link to a supported audio file though, as you mention, and it will play using the native music player when a user presses the link.

[This page](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-DontLinkElementID_2) has a list of supported filetypes.